web aplication using php pdo fulltext search delivers result on ubuntu system but not on windows system; identical DB on both
The setting
Windows 11
Server-Version: 8.4.0 - MySQL Community Server - GPL
Apache/2.4.61 (Win64) PHP/8.3.8
Ubuntu
Server-Version: 10.3.39-MariaDB-0ubuntu0.20.04.2 - Ubuntu 20.04
Apache/2.4.41 (Ubuntu) PHP-Version: 8.3.8
In phpmyadmin this sql
SELECT * FROM `search` WHERE  colname='verlag' and match(what) against( 'O\'reilly' in boolean mode);

delivers results on the Windows system and on Ubuntu allthoug teh DB-system is different.
But my web aplication on Ubuntu delivers results (>0) but in Windows none (==0)
The PHP source on both system is the same as well as the database. The collation
for column what is utf8mb4_german2_ci on both systems.
$this->param->search="O'Reilly";
$this->param->colname="verlag";

$q = "select titleid as id from search where colname=? and match(what) against(? in boolean mode) ";
$ttt = $connect_pdo->prepare($q);
$ttt->execute([$this->param->colname, $this->against($this->param->search)]);

Do I have a PHP problem ?

One way you can test is to turn on the general log while running both queries, then check it to see what exactly was passed in, and compare the two. Make sure to turn the general log back off when you're done, as it will fill up fast.

Turned generl log on and got
On Windows
select titleid as id from search where colname='verlag' and match(what) against(' +O'Reilly' in boolean mode)
on Ubuntu
select titleid as id from search where colname='verlag' and match(what) against(' +O'Reilly' in boolean mode)

It looks to be exactly the same, so I don't think it's a PDO/PHP issue.

Just to be sure - phpMyAdmin still giving you results, when you insert that space and + from your query logs, into the query you are testing in pma as well? Talking about against(' +O\'Reilly' in boolean mode)

@CBroe
On Windows I get no result when using the the query with  ' +' in phpmyadmin, on ubuntu I get a result. Eliminating ' +' from the pattern  I get results on both systems

They're not identical. MySQL and MariaDB are different database products. MariaDB started as a fork of MySQL in 2010, but both have changed a lot of their code since then. You should not assume they are compatible any more.

You have to determine what is different between your code base or connection properties (besides using two different database products, which you should really avoid)  that result in a different results. If phpmyadmin produces the same output, then the issue must be somewhere in your php code.

@Bill Karwin; Then mysql has a bug because it does not deliver results using match(what) against('+O'Reilly' in boolean mode)
When ommiting the '+' I get results. It looks like the "'" or "'" seems to disturb here. What I internaly do is to add '+' in front
of every word in the search pattern so the user does not have to do this when looking for 'this  other  that'
where all words must be present
